# Grand Central Dispatch, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear order of execution confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I'm using GCD for background downloading in my Tab Bar app.

**First step** is to do some background downloading in `-viewWillAppear:` (to setup some basic data before the view is loaded).

**Second step** is to the rest of the background downloading in `-viewDidAppear:`

For some reason, the dispatch block in `-viewDidAppear:` gets called **before** the dispatch block in `-viewWillAppear:`.

This only happens once after loading the application for the first time switching to the tab with the GCD background methods. Switching to another tab and then switching back to the tab with the GCD background methods. The third (and all the rest subsequent times) time I'm switching back it's works as expected (`-viewWillAppear:` firing first and then `-viewDidAppear:`).

Here are excerpts of my code (`-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:`):

**-viewWillAppear:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    DLog(@"viewWillAppear method running");

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        [self setDiskCareerIds:[CareersParser idsFrom:@"disk"]];
        [self setDownloadedCareerIds:[CareersParser idsFrom:@"web"]];


        DLog(@"diskCareerIds after being set in viewWillAppear: %@", [self diskCareerIds])
        DLog(@"downloadedCareerIds after being set in viewWillAppear: %@", [self downloadedCareerIds])

        if ([[self downloadedCareerIds] isEqualToArray:[self diskCareerIds]]) {

            DLog(@"viewWillAppear: ids equal, loading careers from disk.");
            self.careers = [CareersParser loadCareersFromDisk];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.table reloadData];

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];


            });
        }

    });

    //[self downloadData];
}
```

**-viewDidAppear:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    DLog(@"viewDidAppear method running");

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        if (![[self downloadedCareerIds] isEqualToArray:[self diskCareerIds]]) {

            DLog(@"ids not equal, saving careers to disk.");

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self showLoadingView];

            });

            [CareersParser saveCareersToDisk];
            self.careers = [CareersParser loadCareersFromDisk];
        }



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.table reloadData];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

            [self removeLoadingView];

        });
    });

    //[self download3];

    //[self downloadData];
}
```

Check the debug log at [Pastie](http://pastie.org/2222028).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're printing that log message in that first block (the one scheduled in viewWillAppear:) **after** it has done a bunch of parsing, not when it actually starts executing.

The thing is that global queue is a concurrent queue. So even though you are scheduling that first block first, it's not surprising that it sometimes falls behind the other block which is executing concurrently with it.

One simple answer would be to create a serial queue, and then you'll be sure the first block completes before the second one is executed. That seems to be what you want, right?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But either way, shouldn't methods execute FIRST in viewWillAppear? I just don't get it how viewDidAppear gets executed before? However I created my own queue for the dispatch in viewWillAppear with `serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.acando.viewwillappear", 0);` and I release it `dispatch_release(seialQueue);` after the dispatch_async method has run. Also doing the same with the viewDidAppear method but changing values of course. But viewDidAppear dispatch call still runs BEFORE viewWillAppear.

Comment: Well, go ahead and update your question with the current code now that you are using the serial queue and we'll see what's happening now. But in the case of a concurrent queue which you had originally, just because block A is dequeued before block B, that doesn't mean it will necessarily finish executing first. If block A takes a bunch of time to parse things then it could easily fall behind block B and so you get to those log statements in block A after block B has reached its log statements.

Comment: Aha, I think I understand now. The GCD dispatch calls will not "honor" the execution process of viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear when they are running asynchronously. I changed my GCD dispatch call in `viewWillAppear:` to be running synchronously, that way it always seems to finish before the GCD dispatch call in `viewDidAppear:` finishes.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly correct. The queue will still be first-in, first-out. So the first block will start first. BUT, that doesn't mean it will get to the log statements first. The second block could very well make progress more quickly. The two will be executing in parallel. I think making it synchronous is overkill and may well affect your responsiveness.

Comment: It's just two synchronous downloads (not alot of data, maybe 10-20kb). Anyhow how would I solve it asynchronously because I need to have this data downloaded before the other data can start to download...

Comment: Well, innocent little downloads suddenly aren't so innocent when the user is switching networks or in an area of bad signal or something. Then suddenly you've frozen your UI. I think you should look at a serial queue. I know you said that didn't work, but if you post exactly how you tried that then someone can probably help you make that work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I actually got it to work by creating a serial queue in the `viewWillAppear:` method and then in `viewDidAppear:` I'm using the asynchronous call and it works as expected. Methods in the serial queue gets finished before methods in the asynchronous starts.